# JAXB conflict when using OSGi Bundle in NetBeans Platform app (Netigso)

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jaxb, osgi

I have been struggling with this error for an entire day and I just couldn't find any posts out there. This is the error I am getting:

```
org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: my-module-path: Cannot start com.my-bundle state remains INSTALLED after start()
```

This is my scenario:

-I have a NetBeans Platform v7.4 app, that uses an OSGi Module.

-Inside of the OSGi module I have a simple POJO API

-I need to add JAXB annotations "import javax.xml.bind.annotation" to the POJOs because in another non-OSGi module I am saving/reading the model from an XML file

-The OSGi module import works, as long as I do not add the @XML annotations. The moment I add the annotations, I get the error above.

Can somebody help me figure out how do I need to handle the "javax.xml.bind.annotation" import inside of the OSGi bundle? What is causing this error?